# analysing node connectivity difference in a continuous scale (edge weighted by correlations)

Tags: r, graphs

I have an edge list object weighted by a correlation value. I would like to know the changes in the node's connectivity on a continuous scale.

In other words, how does the node connectivity differ from the edge weight scale (-1) to the edge weight (+1)? I would like to know how to do this or whether any R package or statistical model could solve the problems etc.

I would like to know whether node connectivity increases or decreases in relation to the correlation weight. I.e. how it looks at the correlation between node degree and edge weight. But I don't know how to do it.

A example edge list object is created in the code below.

```
data <- structure(list(from = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                       to = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L), 
                   weight = c(runif(18, -1,1))), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -18L), 
                  class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate your help!!
Best,
Amare

Comment: if I understand correctly, something like, "do nodes with higher UNWEIGHTED degree also tend to have higher weight on their edges?"